# How to use entiy queryBuilder in connection queryBuilder?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have two entities: tableUnion, tags.
I created two queryBuilders for them.
How to use it in connection query builder?
I want to keep them remain separate functions.

```
    const entityManager = getManager();
    const connection = getConnection();

    const tableUn = this.tableUnion.createQueryBuilder('tu')
        .select('id')
        .addSelect('description', 'name');

    const tableTg = this.tags.createQueryBuilder('tg')
        .select(['id', 'name']);

    return await connection
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('*')
        .from(
            tableUn => tableUn,
            'tu'
        )
        .addFrom(
            tableTg => tableTg,
            'tg'
        ).getRawMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    return await createQueryBuilder(null, 'u')
        .select('*')
        .from(
            qb => tableUn(qb).from(TableUnion, 'tu'),
            'tu'
        )
        .addFrom(
            qb => tableTg(qb).from(TagsEntity, 'tg'),
            'tg'
        ).getRawMany();
```